# Reset button for template parameters

Tags: templates, module-params

I'm creating a joomla template that allows user to change the template styles (such as font-family setting, bgcolor, text color, etc) from the template backend.

Is it possible to create a reset button, so if you messed up the settings, you can easily revert back **some** fields to the default settings?

There's a workaround [here](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=706&t=806070) but it's incomplete. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there's any built-in option, so as @FFrewin said, a custom form field would be needed. Create a button that resets all input field values to their original state (you will most likely have to manually define these defaults). The user must then click the "save" button

Answer (score 2):

Template style options are saved in `#__template_styles`.`params`.

**A Protostar's sample saved params:**

```
{"templateColor":"#696969","templateBackgroundColor":"#E3E3E3","logoFile":"","googleFont":"1","googleFontName":"Open+Sans","fluidContainer":"0"}
```

So, I guess you will need a custom Field, that will run some update code to set your params of the current template style to a default state.

Comment: Yes, I think so. Thanks. Anyway, I just want to reset styles related params values only and leave the other untouched. Is it possible?

Comment: what are the related params? One idea would be to have in your update statement all the default params value, that will reset the template style.

Comment: Let say I have 4 fields, field A to control font-family, filed B to control web background color, field C to control text color, field D to control custom code for adding in <head> section. I want when user click the reset button, it will reset A,B,C only. Field D will not be modified.

Comment: Well, first I think you need to somehow know the current style's id, which I m not sure if there is a straight-forward way to have this in the edit style  interface of the template's manager -if there isn't, then you will have to get it inside your custom field-, then you can first fetch the saved params and use any of these values inside your update statement.

Comment: Hmm, ok. Will try it and update my question soon. Thanks!